# Python I explicitly returned None but got nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I explicitly returned `None` in the base case but the doctest tell it got **nothing**.

Here is my code:

```
def find_triple(ilist):
    """ Find a triple of integers x, y, z in the list ilist such that x + y = z.
    Return the tuple (x, y). If the triple does not exist, return None.

    >>> find_triple([4,5,9]) in [(4,5), (5,4)]
    True
    >>> li = [(30,70), (70,30), (20,50), (50,20), (20,30), (30,20)]
    >>> find_triple([20,40,100,50,30,70]) in li
    True
    >>> find_triple([6,11,7,2,3])
    None
    >>> find_triple([1, 1, 3])
    None
    """
    # define a yield function to reduce the cost of time and space
    def yield_pair(ilist):
        """ enumerate all the two pairs in the list.

        >>> g = yield_pair([4,5,9])
        >>> next(g)
        (4, 5)
        >>> next(g)
        (4, 9)
        >>> next(g)
        (5, 9)
        >>> next(g)
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
        StopIteration
        """
        for i in range(len(ilist) - 1):
            for j in range(i, len(ilist) - 1):
                yield (ilist[i], ilist[j + 1])

    # first turn the ilist into a set, so the `in` operation is much more efficient
    iset = set(ilist)
    g = yield_pair(ilist)
    while True:
        try:
            pair = next(g)
            if sum(pair) in iset:
                return pair
        except StopIteration:
            return None  # ********  problems here ****************
        except:
            return None  # ******** verbose I just try to show that it does not return None *******
```

Here is my error message:

```
Failed example:
    find_triple([6,11,7,2,3])
Expected:
    None
Got nothing
```

Comment: Python doesn't return nothing.. When i try `print(find_triple([6,11,7,2,3]))` i get `None`..

Answer (score 5):

The `None` value will be ignored.  You can use the following:

```
""" Find a triple of integers x, y, z in the list ilist such that x + y = z.
Return the tuple (x, y). If the triple does not exist, return None.
>>> find_triple([6,11,7,2,3]) is None
True
>>> find_triple([1, 1, 3]) is None
True
"""
```

Answer (score 4):

The REPL always ignores `None` as a return value, printing nothing. Either skip the output for that line or explicitly print the return value.

Comment: OK! Thanks! Really fast reply. I appreciated that.

Answer (score 1):

Shells never display a `None` result.  But "no output at all" is also a result `doctest` can check for.  So instead of this part:

```
>>> find_triple([6,11,7,2,3])
None
>>> find_triple([1, 1, 3])
None
"""
```

you can just remove the "None" lines:

```
>>> find_triple([6,11,7,2,3])
>>> find_triple([1, 1, 3])
"""
```

Then `doctest` will complain if they *don't* return `None`.  Or you can explicitly print the result:

```
>>> print(find_triple([6,11,7,2,3]))
None
>>> print(find_triple([1, 1, 3]))
None
"""
```

Or, as already suggested, you could tack on `is None` and show that you expect a `True` result.  Or ...

Which one is best?  Whichever way *you* find clearest.  I would have done it the first way above, but then I never expected `None` to be displayed to begin with ;-)